# Installing Phonegap/Cordova 3.1 plugins (barcodescanner)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Been trying this for a few hours now and have made a little progress but not in the right direction.

I have successfully setup an Android Cordova project which loads onto a phone and runs fine. I just cannot get the barcode scanner plugin to work in Cordova 3.1. I believe it has installed correctly but it does not appear in the config.xml, it does however appear in the cordova_plugins.js file etc.

I have this in my index.js

```
function clickScan() {
    var scanner = cordova.require("com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner");
    scanner.scan(
        function (result) {
            alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
        }, 
        function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
   );
}
```

Now when I press the scan button it seems to run this code but jumps straight to the success function and just displays the alert box with blank results.

The scanner I am using and have installed via cordova plugin add is https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner

I am **not** currently importing the barcodescanner.js file into the html as I have done with older versions of cordova as I believe this is handled differently in 3+ and seems to be defined in the cordova_plugins.js file?

**Update**: As far as I am aware with the config above there does not seem to be any glaring errors popup in Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, You dont need to import any plugin specific javascript file in your index.html.
Just Verify that plugin in properly installed in your project by confirming YourProject/res/config.xml file has the following entry:

```
<feature name="BarcodeScanner">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" />
</feature>
```

For using the plugin, just use the updated syntax of calling the plugin functions -

```
function clickScan() {
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
  }, 
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  });}
```

Comment: Upon double checking I had it in the Res folder I realised that I had missed some steps that are not immediately obvious. I needed to run the build command from the root folder and that would push the plugin to all platforms, thanks for your help!

Comment: This does not work for me with cordova 3.3.1-0.1.2. What exactly do you mean with updated syntax? Is this an undocumented change? If so, could you point me to the source? In the developer docs, the syntax is cordova.exec('<plugin.ref>') http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: i think it will refers to barcodescanner api syntax: it passed from 
`var scanner = window.cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");
 scanner.scan(function (result) {}, function (error) {});
}`
to simple window.plugins.barcodeScanner, and finally to cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner